# Browser doesn't recognize HTTPS

Tags: tls, web-application, web-browser

I am having a strange issue reported from a client:

[image]

This browser doesn't show HTTPS secured and accredited connection, although my site has HTTPS. Normally, on other browsers they show.

For example:

`[Company Security Certificate] www.blahblahblah`

I don't know which browser this is. I have tried to reproduce with all the latest versions of the following:

- Edge
- IE11
- Chrome
- Firefox Quantum
- Firefox Developer Edition
- Opera
- SeaMonkey

However, all of them show HTTPS. This browser looks like a Windows platform because it has Windows outlook, so I can cross Safari off of the list.

Does anyone have a slight chance to recognize this browser or offer any explanation?

Comment: Does your site not serve port 80 at all?

Comment: I don't recognize the browser, but https is only the default for your site if you use HSTS preloading (with certain browsers). So unless you're redirecting to the https:// version of the site, this would be normal when they type your web page in without the protocol. The weird look of the browser could be a theme/customization. Chrome supports this, for example, though it still doesn't quite look like Chrome.

Comment: To get a definitive answer, ask the client who submitted the report.

Comment: Do they have a proxy between you and them that does not use https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have them go to an https url. So make sure they aren't just going to www.yoursite.com, but click the link https://www.yoursite.com:443

If that doesn't show, try disabling http or closing port 80 on your server in an effort to trouble shoot and confirm it actually https. Have them use wireshark to take a capture and look for tls handshake. If that doesn't work there is a likelihood that your customer has been Man in the Middle attacked with something called ssl stripping. That would be very bad news.

This could be the signs of a cyber attack, so I recommend investigating quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The browser does not seem identifiable to me from the screenshot. However to make sure your site always uses HTTPS, you should:

- Always [redirect to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083221/how-to-redirect-all-http-requests-to-https)
- Add [HSTS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet)
- Add [CSP header](https://content-security-policy.com/) with at least https: specified, you can and should be more detailed if you can.